# Hello World for Intuit Anywhere Java find customers not working

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

After making the successful connection to Intuit using OpenID, and clicking FindAllCustomers link (making sure the customers (only 2 customers) are existing in my Intuit's Account), which uses the following set of code in JSP:

```
QBCustomerService customerService = null;
    try {
        // Create the customer service.
        customerService = QBServiceFactory.getService(context,
                QBCustomerService.class);
    } catch (QBInvalidContextException e) {
        System.out.println("(QBInvalidContextException thrown by getService: " + e.getMessage());
    }

     try {
        // Using the service, retrieve all customers and display their names.
        List<QBCustomer> customers = customerService
            .findAll(context, 1, 100);

    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception thrown by findAll: " + e.getMessage());
     }
```

I get the following ERROR:

```
SEVERE: Error: 500 
Exception thrown by findAll: com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSException: 
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSRestClient.sendRequest(IDSRestClient.java:521)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSRestClient.post(IDSRestClient.java:164)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.qbo.QBORequestCreator.doIDSPost(QBORequestCreator.java:28)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.qbo.AbstractQBOBaseDataService.findAll(AbstractQBOBaseDataService.java:170)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.qbo.QBOCustomerService.findAll(QBOCustomerService.java:127)
    at org.apache.jsp.findallcustomers_jsp._jspService(findallcustomers_jsp.java:131)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know if anything I'm missing or doing anything wrong. Also, do let me know if you want to know more about any configuration I'm doing to setup this application.

**EDIT**

Even after compiling the V3 App suggested by Manas Ref - https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java

during launching this app, I'm getting this error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intuit/ipp/exception/FMSException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:962)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 40 more

Jul 07, 2014 1:20:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet qbapiv3
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intuit.ipp.exception.FMSException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:962)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have double checked that the FMSException class is still there in the Library that I downloaded and made available in the class path from [here](https://intuitcorp.quickbase.com/up/bhvhx8wfg/g/re/eg/va/ipp-v3-java-devkit-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar)
 .

**EDIT**
 I have somehow setup the QuickBooks version 2 for connectivity purposes and utilizing the Version-3 libraries for performing the DML in QuickBooks (Creating / Fetching a Customer - working fine). However, I can't fathom out why I'm not able to setup the QuickBooks version-3 as a Java application.

My main motto behind using the QuickBooks is to have an external application executes whenever there's DML in QuickBooks. I don't know if the QuickBooks has such facility:

1. Writing trigger for specific objects or,
2. Some kind of push notifications to the clients (Publisher - Subscriber model) - Here, Publisher would be QuickBooks account and Subscriber would be our registered application. (triggers whenever any DML happens).

Please let me know your suggestions for this.

Comment: 500 error generally comes when the tokens are expired or the company subscription has ended. Check if that is the case. Try regenerating your OAuth tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You're using JAVA V2 sample app. V2 APIs are deprecated and you can't access Global company's data using V2.

Please use the V3 sample app 
Ref - https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java

Setup instruction is available here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code/spring_sample_app_for_quickbooksapi/0002_creating_the_app

Maven command -

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.intuit.code.devkit.v3 -DartifactId=ipp-v3-java-devkit -Dversion=2.3.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=<JarFilePath>\ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

PN - If required please change the version number according to the devkit version you have.
Latest devkit is available here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

Re - Qts on Push notification
As of now, this service is not available in production. There are couple of existing solutions which you should find out after doing a bit googling.

**Imp** - You should not use the deprecated V2 app.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for getting back. It seems while setting up the Quickbooks V3 API, it was not compiling the POM and not able to satisfy the dependency and even after making the pom ready, I'm not able to execute it. Please see my updates in starting V3 API in my Question itself.

Comment: Had you installed the dependencies as mentioned in the following setup guide ?
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code/spring_sample_app_for_quickbooksapi/0002_creating_the_app#Step_5:_Install_the_Dependencies

In the mvn command, please use the latest devkit version number(i.e 2.3.1). ipp-java-qbapihelper jar is available as part of the devkit archive. It should work. 
Please let us if you are still facing any issue. 

Thanks

Comment: Manas, I'm not able to install the dependencies using mvn command either. Let me know if the error stack trace would help you understanding. See the output here: http://pastebin.com/S5njS8Lm (QuickBooks Mvn Output)

Comment: After making some amendments to the POM (here: http://pastebin.com/H9aJdY9J), I'm getting different error and it seems it downloaded some information as well. The error now I'm getting is: http://pastebin.com/UdRWSZVH. Please let me know about this. I have also mentioned in the POM that the 3 dependencies are not working (not compiling)

Comment: Please see my edits and let me know if there's a possibility of setting up an application (as a background application). Means, user will only interact with the standard QuickBooks pages and behind the screen our setup application would listen to the DML events happening for that specific QuickBooks account (like push notification service). Any idea!

Comment: Sanchit, did you follow the stpes mentioned in this link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code/spring_sample_app_for_quickbooksapi/0002_creating_the_app 
I guess not or it was not done properly. Log says - "The specified file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\QuickbooksV3API-Java\QuickbooksV3API\JarFilePath\ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar' not exists". It clearly suggests that devkit is not properly installed. Updating the maven command in my above post.